# Inconsistency between regex and python search

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I'm doing a small regex that catch all the text before the numbers.
https://regex101.com/r/JhIiG9/2

```py
import re

regex = "^(.*?)(\d*([-.]\d*)*)$"
message = "Myteeeeext  0.366- 0.3700"
result = re.search(regex, message)
print(result.group(1))
```

https://www.online-python.com/a7smOJHBwp

When I run this regex instead of just showing the first group which is `Myteeeeext`   I'm getting `Myteeeeext  0.366-`  but in regex101 it shows only

Comment: try `^(.*?)(?:\d*(?:[-.]\d*)*)$` or `^(.*?)(?:\d*[.-]?)*$`

Comment: nope not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Regex, `[^\d.-]+`

It catches all the text before the numbers

```py
import re

regex = "[^\d.-]+"
message = "Myteeeeext  0.366- 0.3700 notMyteeeeext"
result = re.search(regex, message)
print(f"'{result.group()}'")
```

Outputs:

```
'Myteeeeext  '
```

tell me if its okay for you...

Comment: unfortunately i'm also trying to get the `0.366- 0.3700` in the second group I'll work around your regex thank

Comment: @Biscuit then try something like `([^\d.-]+)([\d. -]+)` it would work

Answer (score 0):

Your regex:

```
regex = "^(.*?)(\d*([-.]\d*)*)$"
```

doesn't allow for the numbers part to have any spaces, but your search string:

```
message = "Myteeeeext  0.366- 0.3700"
```

does have a space after the dash, so this part of your regex:

```
(.*?)
```

matches up to the second number.

It doesn't look like your test string in the regex101.com example you gave has a space, so that's why your results are different.

Comment: it does have that space if you look at it https://regex101.com/r/JhIiG9/2

Comment: Not after the ```-```, that's the difference. Your example in your question has a space after the dash.

Comment: oh you're totally right, devils lies in details